# How do I access request params inside a CarrierWave uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Is it possible to access the request params from here?
end
```

I'm letting the user do some customization on the image, so the user would specify some options in the form then select a file, and hit upload. On the server side, how do I access those params from the form inside the CarrierWave uploader?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible, or even if it is - it should be considered as a bad practice. However you can access your model attributes here like this:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version :preview do
    process :user_resize
  end

  protected

  def user_resize
    if model.user_width and model.user_height
      #do something here
    end
  end
end
```